# Backup Maria DB data that is already down in docker but the data is persistent

Tags: docker, mariadb

MariaDB (running in Docker), whose storage is mounted on a drive of the host machine is currently down. I can navigate to the storage in Linux and can see the data. How do I back it up as the usual backup commands cannot work because the MariaDB is currently down.

I am new to docker and Database
Another instance of the Server has been spinnedup in docker and working but I want to restore the data of the old server to the new one.
`docker ps -a` shows that one mariadb is down and the other one is up

Comment: What about bringing the down instance up ?

Comment: I have tried to bring it up but it wouldn't.  By bringing up the new instance, I have allocated its port (3306) to another instance.

Comment: Then change the port (maybe only temporarily?)  to something different , see: [How to change the default port of mysql from 3306 to 3360](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29866204/how-to-change-the-default-port-of-mysql-from-3306-to-3360)

Comment: The Instance had been down before i reallocated it. Now that I tried to assign a new port, it is not recognising it because it is down.


Is it technically possible to move its data to the running instance?